# python script error- with GetParameterAsText

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, error-000539

I have a seemingly simple code which iterates through a list of feature classes and calculates an ID field in the attribute table that is equal to the first 5 characters of feature class name.  The script works fine if I hard code the workspace.  As soon as I change it to "Get Parameter as Text"  I receive this error:

ERROR 000539: Error running expression: expression : name 'expression' is not defined
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

The script is:

```
import arcpy, sys, array, time, datetime

#Get feature dataset
inws = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Set geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.workspace = inws
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Iterate through the list of feature classes

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcList:
    print str("processing" + fc)

#Define field and expression
field = "SID"
expression = str(fc[:5])

#Create a new field name and expression
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, field, "TEXT")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, field, "expression", "PYTHON")
```

does anyone know what is going on here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems.  First, the way it's indented won't iterate through the featureclasses and perform the process on each, it will just iterate through and print your print statement.  Second, your expression should be built with quotes around it (at least that's the case for VB syntax) and called as a variable and not a string.

Try the following:

```
import arcpy, sys, array, time, datetime

#Get feature dataset
inws = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Set geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.workspace = inws
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#set the field name
field = "SID"

#Iterate through the list of feature classes   
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  
for fc in fcList:
    print str("processing" + fc)

    #Define expression
    expression = "\"" + fc[:5] + "\""

    #Create a new field name and expression
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, field, "TEXT")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, field, expression)
```

Note that I took out the "PYTHON" option on CalculateField... I generally use the default VB syntax for simple operations, so I think this should work.

Also, touching on what R.K. was saying about GetParameterAsText(0) not being assigned a value, I'm assuming you're running this as a script tool in ArcMap in which you've mapped out an input to assign to Parameter(0).  It should work in this case if your input is mapped as a workspace, otherwise if you're not running it as a script tool, (s)he's right, it needs input.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.  I still don't understand though why my script only seemed to fail when I changed the input workspace (inws) to a Get parameter as Text) value.  The script worked perfectly when I had the workspace hardcoded to a test database.  Then, as soon as I changed it so it was suitable to add as a tool into toolbox, it failed with the expression.  Thanks again though- I really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Glad I could help.  Python works in mysterious ways... at least to me.  I've been spending a lot of time lately hunting down errors that suddenly pop up when I run things as a script tool.  Usually it's some very picky syntax like in your case.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should catch [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html). Otherwise you won't really know where things go wrong and how to handle unexpected behavior.  Something else: Note that if your workspace ends with a single `\` python will interpret this as a escape which will result in a invalid path.

To ensure you always have a valid workspace do:

```
if inws[-1:] != '\\':
    inws += '\\'
```

To handle exceptions:

```
try:
    #Set geoprocessing environments
    arcpy.env.workspace = inws
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

except:
   msg = arcpy.getmessages()
   raise Exception(msg)
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is most probably with the last line.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, field, "expression", "PYTHON")
```

It should be the variable `expression` and not the string `"expression"` as [@PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo) pointed out.

Comment: And on the CalculateField I am betting @user10723 will want a variable called expression rather than the string "expression" too.

Comment: @R.K., it's not true that nothing get assigned to `inws`: `arcpy.env.workspace = inws`.

Comment: Nothing gets assigned if he's running it as a standalone script. Otherwise, you're right.

Comment: But that's the whole point, right? To run it from the toolbox - or am I missing something essential?

Comment: I was just considering the possibility that he used a standalone script. But upon closer inspection, you're right. He was using it as tool. Missed the fact that `ERROR 000539` is an ArcGIS error code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks RK- The expression worked fine when the path the feature dataset was hardcoded.  So, it is strange to me that it would decide that the syntax was incorrect only when I changed the input workspace (inws) to a Get Parameter as Text.  I am new to Python Scripting, so I am just trying to understand why this change would create thee error I received.